# Sorry, we were not able to find a user with that username and password

Tags: spring, security, grails-plugin

I installed the `Spring Security core` plug-in 1.2.7.3 on `Grails 2.1.1`, ran the `s2-quickstart` command, and then initialized the initial user and roles in the bootstrap.groovy, but I still cannot login. Text of the relevant piece of `BootStrap.groovy` follows:

```
    if (SecRole.count == 0) {
        def fUserRole = SecRole.findByAuthority('ROLE_FlowUser') ?: new SecRole(authority: 'ROLE_FlowUser').save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
        def fAdminRole = SecRole.findByAuthority('ROLE_FlowAdmin') ?: new SecRole(authority: 'ROLE_FlowAdmin').save(failOnError: true, flush: true)

        def bf = SecUser.findByUsername('bill') ?: new SecUser(
                username: 'bill',
                password: 'eagle',
                firstName: 'bill',
                lastName: 'fly',
                email: 'bill.fly@baylorhealth.edu',
                accountExpired: false,
                accountLocked: false,
                passwordExpired: false,
                enabled: true
        ).save(failOnError: true, flush: true)

        if (!bf.authorities.contains(fAdminRole)) {
            SecUserSecRole.create bf, fAdminRole, true
        }
        if (!bf.authorities.contains(fUserRole)) {
            SecUserSecRole.create bf, fUserRole, true
        }
    }
```

I am not encrypting the password in bootstrap, as seems to be the answer to most of the questions of this type.  All four records are getting written to the database tables, but of course, I cannot tell if the password is encrypted correctly.  My initial controller has the following annotation ahead of the class statement:

```
@Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'])
```

Also, I added the following to the config.groovy:

// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'cocktail.SecUser'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'cocktail.SecUserSecRole'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.authority.className = 'cocktail.SecRole'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.password.algorithm = 'SHA-256'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your password may be encoded two times (problem may occure if you are using multi datasources).

Try this :

```
class User {
    ...
    transient bEncoded = false
    ...
    protected void encodePassword() {
        if (!bEncoded ) { 
            password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password); 
            bEncoded = true; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That fixed it!  Two datasources causes the beforeInsert to be executed twice, but the code above keeps the encoding from happening twice.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the `authorities.contains` check is failing because of missing `hashCode` and `equals` methods in your role class. But if there are no roles (your 1st check) then the user wouldn't have any granted, so you can just remove those checks:

```
SecUserSecRole.create bf, fAdminRole, true
SecUserSecRole.create bf, fUserRole, true
```

If that doesn't fix it, it's most likely a password encoding issue - add debug logging for Spring Security and it should show you why it's failing; add `debug 'org.springframework.security'` in your log4j block in Config.groovy

p.s. `if (SecRole.count == 0) {` should be `if (SecRole.count() == 0) {` or just `if (!SecRole.count()) {`

Comment: Two roles, one user, and two user-role rows are being written.